# In Scala, other than inheritance is there a technique to know when a base class method has been called?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

For example, suppose I have the following base class for which I cannot modify the source code

```
class Base {
    def someMethod = ...
}
```

If I define a sub class

```
class Sub extends Base {
    override def someMethod = ...
}
```

when I do

val sub = new Sub

Then I automatically "know" when someMethod has been called because sub.someMethod is triggered. However I would like to avoid subclassing so I was wondering if there was some technique whereby I could do

```
class NotSubclass {
    val Base = new Base
}
```

or similar

And somehow "attach" someMethod from Base so that NotSubclass would "know" when someMethod was called. To clarify someMethod is called externally I never make the call in my own code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are modifying the behaviour of a class for which you don't have the source code, then you could try looking into [Aspect-Oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Aspects allow you to 'wrap' a method call so that you can log information, or modify the input parameters or return values, or even just replace the method call altogether.

If all you want to do is log information, then this would be a good way to go. However, Aspects can lead to code which is very hard to understand and follow if you use them everywhere, so be sure that it fits your use case.

You will need to define a [pointcut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointcut) for the method you are interested in.

The [Scala-IDE](http://www.scala-ide.org/) uses aspects to weave code into the JDT, it uses [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), so it does work with Scala.

Comment: @deltanovember: so you can't change the source code but somehow postprocessing the compiled class file is fine?

Answer (score 2):

If the method belongs to an interface you can reimplement that and wrap Base. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
class NotSubclass {
    val base = new Base

    def someMethod = base someMethod
}
```

Comment: Not quite because if base.someMethod is called externally, I would like NotSubclass.someMethod to automatically be called

Comment: Oh you mean, any time anyone *ever* calls `Base.someMethod`, regardless of whether they have your `NotSubclass`?

Comment: For a concrete examples, suppose Base automatically starts getting stock market data upon instantiation. I would like some sort of notification every time the price is updated (via someMethod) in NotSubclass

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it using byte code manipulation. PowerMock allows to mock constructors, so I'd guess the same technique could be used to replace the byte code of Base with something that does whatever you need to get done.

This approach of course will:

- be extremely confusing for anybody being not aware of it.
- fail if you don't have the classloaders under your control.
- might break legal constraints
- is just generally a bad idea for production code.